# How to add emoji picker in flutter

Tags: flutter, custom-keyboard

I am trying to add emoji picker in my flutter app. I already tried some packages like `emoji_picker_flutter`, but I found it really laggy and inefficient. Are there any other options. I was hoping at least to be able to open the emoji section in the user's keyboard but found that it's impossible to control the user keyboard unless the user actually presses the emoji button on the keyboard. Does someone have any ideas if there is like another package or SDK that can provide me with this ? My last resort is to build the keyboard manually with like `PageView()` and so many buttons.

Comment: have you tried emoji_selector: ^0.0.6 ?